# change the position of div according to offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the position of div according to offset ie top, bottom, left, right is it possible ? 
i have tried some jquery but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var offset = $("#myPopup").offset();
  $('#popup').css('left',offset.left);    
  $('#popup').css('top',offset.top);

}); 
<div id="myPopup"> popup</div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem. Also please check if your #popup element is a positioned element. Try adding position: relative.

Comment: basically i am working on a pop up which can be positioned at any corner of window depending on the value from db .

Comment: Then I think you should probably use position:fixed in css, so it will be relative to the view port rather than body. But this won't scroll with the page scroll, if you don't want that.

Comment: position should be able  change according to vaue from db

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you did not use a position type in your style. I've put it in your jQuery for easy test, but you better put that in a css...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var offset = $("#myPopup").offset();
  $('#popup').css('position','relative');//or absolute.
  $('#popup').css('left',offset.left);    
  $('#popup').css('top',offset.top);

}); 
<div id="myPopup"> popup</div>
```

Comment: @ Salketer can we set the div at any psition of window  using above code, means if want my div to appear in right of screen .

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp it lists all the possible values and how they can impact positioning. Choose the one that fits best for you.